# Define which function to use according two parameters with an infinity of combinations in C#

Tags: c#, generics, enums, coordinate-transformation

I have a problem which must be solved by a design pattern which is unknown to me. This is for transformations between different coordinate systems. I explain to you.

1/ I have an enum referencing a collection of system (EPSG):

```
public enum System
{
    NAD27 = 3800,
    NAD83 = 3801,
    ...
    WGS84 = 4326
}
```

These enum allows to define the system of use by an object Coordinate.

```
public struct Coordinate
{
    public System system;

    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;
}
```

There can be an infinity of systems. The enum indexes do not necessarily follow each other and must not be modified.

2/ It is necessary that objects can pass from one system to another. I apply transformations from one system to another. System A -> System B. 
This transformation does not change the type. It changes the values of the coordinate (x, y and z) so that the point is in the right place depending on its system.

All combinations are possible. However, depending on the starting system, the calculations for changing systems are not always the same.

3/ I have several static classes containing the transformation methods:

```
public static class WGS84
{
    public static Coordinate ToNAD27 (double X, double Y, double Z)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static Coordinate ToNAD83 (double X, double Y, double Z)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

We come to the problem.

4/ To define which transformation used and to avoid lots of if I first used a switch taking as argument an object containing the starting system and the arriving system:

```
public class SystemTransform
{
    public System initial;
    public System terminal;
}


public struct Coordinate 
{
    public System system;

    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;


    public Coordinate Transform (SystemTransform s)
    {
        switch(s)
        {
            case SystemTransform st when st.Initial == System.WGS84 && st.Terminal == System.NAD27:
                        return WGS84.ToNAD27(X, Y, Z);

            ...

            case SystemTransform st when st.Initial == System.WGS84 && st.Terminal == System.Z:
                        throw new NotImplementedException ($ "{s} not implmented");
        }
    }
}
```

5/ Being impractical and aesthetic, I turned to a dictionary:

```
public static class TransformWithDictionary
{
        private static Dictionary <SystemTransform, Func <Coordinate , Coordinate >> ParserMap = new Dictionary <SystemTransform, Func <Coordinate , Coordinate >>
        {
            {new SystemTransform (System.WGS84, System.NAD27), coord => WGS84.ToNAD27(coord)},
            {new SystemTransform (System.WGS84, System.NAD83), coord => WGS84.ToNAD83(coord)},
        };

        public MyObject GetParserFor (SystemTransform st, Coordinate coord)
        {
            if (! ParserMap.ContainsKey(st))
                throw new NotImplementedException ("Unexpected file type value" + st);

            return ParserMap[st](coord);
        }
}
```

It's a little more classy, ​​but that doesn't correct the problem.

In theory I am facing a switch with ∞ possibility. Suffice to say that it is not possible to fill it by hand and maintain it over time.

The third idea was to make a factory. But that does nothing to help me to define which function to use according to the system of origin and the system of arrived.

Any idea of ​​a design pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: Seems like `MyObject` is quite mutable and not a good candidate for a `struct`.

Comment: The `case` statements seem to completely ignore the `switch` vairable `s`. Does that actually work?

Comment: If you'll have different transformations and those have to be hand coded, then I don't get the "a switch with infinite possibilities" statement, you still have to write infinite transformations so where's the point?

Comment: What kind of code do you have in `ToSystemB`, `ToSystemX` etc? If they are _really_ all different, then your problem is _inherently_ complex. The only way I can think of is encoding the logic in a data file (or not encode, but actually write it in a DSL that you will invent). This way, the C# code just needs to find a correct file, reads it, and runs it. The file name could begin with the `initial` system and end with the `terminal` system.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you trying to achieve at the end but you may want to look at [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8). If you are trying to automatically to compute whether there is a path transforming A to B via C1,C2,..CN types then you should read on path finding on graphs. You also may look into implementations of "unit of measure" conversions...

Comment: , Sorry, I don't have my code in front of me, it is made from memory. I look at what has been done exactly in a short time.

@Sweeper, The code in ToSystemB, ToSystemX etc contains coordinate transformations according to geodetic systems. There are commonalities and differences depending on the starting system and the finishing system. The idea of a DSL was on the list but I was not sure that it was a good practice in my case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, It is not really a type conversion problem. The struct does not change, it is the variables contained in it that adapts according to the system. I realize that my problem is not explained well enough, I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i fully understand your requirement, but to me it sounds like a simple abstraction is enough.

```
    public abstract class CoordinateSystem
    {
        public double X {get; private set; }
        public double Y {get; private set; }
        public double Z {get; private set; }

        protected CoordinateSystem( Double x, Double y, Double z )
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }

        public abstract CoordinateSystemA ToA();
        public abstract CoordinateSystemB ToB();
        public abstract CoordinateSystemC ToC();
    }

    public class CoordinateSystemA : CoordinateSystem
    {
        public CoordinateSystemA( Double x, Double y, Double z )
          : base(x, y, z )
        {}

        public override CoordinateSystemA ToA() {
            return new CoordinateSystemA(X,Y,Z);
        }
        public override CoordinateSystemB ToB() {
            return new CoordinateSystemB(2,2,2);
        }
        public override CoordinateSystemC ToC() {
            return new CoordinateSystemC(3,3,3);
        }
    }

    public class CoordinateSystemB : CoordinateSystem
    {
        public CoordinateSystemB( Double x, Double y, Double z )
          : base(x, y, z )
        {}

        public override CoordinateSystemA ToA() {
            return new CoordinateSystemA(1,1,1);
        }
        public override CoordinateSystemB ToB() {
            return new CoordinateSystemB(X,Y,Z);
        }
        public override CoordinateSystemC ToC() {
            return new CoordinateSystemC(3,3,3);
        }
    }

    public class CoordinateSystemC : CoordinateSystem
    {
        public CoordinateSystemC( Double x, Double y, Double z )
          : base(x, y, z )
        {}

        public override CoordinateSystemA ToA() {
            return new CoordinateSystemA(1,1,1);
        }
        public override CoordinateSystemB ToB() {
            return new CoordinateSystemB(2,2,2);
        }
        public override CoordinateSystemC ToC() {
            return new CoordinateSystemC(X,Y,Z);
        }
    }


    public static class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            CoordinateSystem coordinateSystem = new CoordinateSystemA(1,1,1);
            CoordinateSystem b = coordinateSystem.ToB();
            CoordinateSystem c = b.ToC();
        }
    }
```

By putting `ToX();` on the abstract class it forces all, inherit, coordinate systems (classes) to implement the conversion. You can then use the abstract class throughout your system without knowing the system, and easily convert to the system you want.

If this do not fulfill your requirements, i think you should take a look at the Visitor Pattern. It is a bit more complex, but there is lot of examples out there.